# a question about convergence of sequecce!I have tried cauchy method, but it doesn't work

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

suppose $a_n>0$,and$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i$ is convergent,so we need to prove 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{ {1\over n}(a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{2n})}$ is also convergent!

I have tried cauchy method, but maybe it doesn't work! 
most of the normal methods have been tried by me, but I am always stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i$ is convergent and therefore there is $N$ such that for all $n>N$ and all $m\geq 1$ we have:
$$
a_{n+1}+\dots+a_{n+p}<\epsilon.
$$
In this case we have:
$$
{ {1\over n+1}(a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots+a_{2n+2})}+\dots+{ {1\over n+p}(a_{n+p}+a_{n+p+1}+\cdots+a_{2n+2p})}\\
\leq {1\over n+1}\epsilon+\dots+ {1\over n+p}\epsilon\leq \frac{p}{n+p}\epsilon\leq \epsilon.
$$
This means that the second series satisfy Cauchy convergence criterion and is convergent.